# Is there a trick to apply style to a background image?

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
#lego{
    background: url(images/lego.png) no-repeat center bottom ;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="lego"></div>
```

Without adding any tag or HTML.

Without Javascript.

lego is 100% wide, while the image is not.

How to apply `box-shadow` (or other styling) specifically to the image only (not to the 100% wide lego element).

Comment: I don't think there is. you can try and edit the image itself, or create multiple instances of it and change the class when needed.

Comment: Or make it a foreground image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use css [pseudo :before or :after elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) to contain your image so that you could just give `:before` element a shadow but not the lego div. Check out this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cNeWW/

```
#lego{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#lego:before{
    content: "";
    background: url(images/lego.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    position: absolute;
    width: <background width>;
    height: <background height>;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #000;
}
```

Comment: Nice trick indeed. Works even in IE9. Thanks. Oooh, by the way, lego must be the name of that sheep then. :)

Comment: haha. The sheeps real name is Sparkles she is a great pet I have.

Answer (score 5):

No. Add a shadow to the actual image.

Edit:
CSS3 allows for multiple backgrounds though, so maybe you can get tricky with that.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to style an image that is a background image of an element. The background image is part of the styling of the element.

You can use an `<img>` tag (using position and box-shadow) to do this, or add a shadow to the image itself in Photoshop or another image editing program.

This cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. CSS styles are applied to DOM elements, background image is not a DOM element. You can do something like this:

CSS:

```
#lego .image {
    background: url(images/lego.png) no-repeat center bottom ;
    width: <image_width>;
    height: <image_height>;
    box-shadow: ...
    ...
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lego">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not possible. CSS can style only HTML elements, and background image is not an element. But you can either add a shadow to the image itself (using photoshop or sth alike), or you can try to use `#logo:after` and play with that, perhaps it can do what you intended.